Fixing Lip Between Shower and Wall for Bathroom Wall Tile Installation
I just finished doing the bulk of the demo in our bathroom after having all of our drains redone and am in the process of putting everything back together. We want to install six inch white square wall tiles halfway up the walls, and were hoping to leave the shower the way it is for now, both cause the tile we would want is backordered, and just for budget reasons (those new drains were not cheap).
Previously there was a vanity close to where the bathtub was, and after pulling this out I discovered this gradual lip between the shower wall and the drywall. At the top the surfaces are flush to each other, but by the bottom there's a bit more than an inch difference. Also, looking towards the bottom few tiles by the tub, it seems like there is some sort of material behind the tile, and the tile is pretty loose. The previous owners of this house made a ton of bad decisions, and I am sure this is the result of some hack job fix of theirs. I am not sure what's the best way to address this.


While I was hoping to do this install myself, I did get some quotes for this. All of the contractors I spoke to point towards the best option being to remove the whole shower and start the whole bathroom over. While I definitely understand that that would probably lead to the best long term result, I still have to ask: is there any way to just repair these bottom few tiles and install the rest of the wall tiles? Do I have no choice but to rip out the entire shower? I would love to rip it out and do something nicer eventually, but it would be awesome to have a working bathroom while we save the money up for it.
One option one of the contractors mentioned was to try to solve it by installing schulter edge trim as best as you could. I don't mind leaving a lip and having some sort of trim piece, but the fact that it sticks out at the bottom but is flush at the top leaves me unsure as to how that would work. My current idea is I could install some cement boards and shim it out some, and try my best to get the edge right. I don't need it to be perfect or anything, but I am just trying to figure out what my best course of action might be.
Thanks!

There is no good solution for this. It looks like the drywall is bonded to the concrete (?) block and that the whole wall is out or that the drywall was not installed plumb for whatever reason, explaining your taper.
Putting an edge along the entire line of tile vertically will make the unevenness of the wall stand out more (although some of it may be hidden by the sink and cabinet). Putting the edge around all of the tile means a lot of cutting of the edge or grooving out the wall to allow for the depth of the edge.
Your most economical solution is to remount the tile at the bottom and put a nice silicone bead to finish the edge. There is only so much you can change because you must follow both the vertical and horizontal planes of the adjoining tile. Put the money you save towards a proper reno. A change in color scheme can make the features less obvious.

Got it, thank you! I think its the tile that isn't plumb but I could be wrong. Either way this gives me a way to get this sorted until I have the budget for the full reno. I would be surprised if this shower gets used even once between now and then, so I think we're okay to do this to tide us over. We're also planning to change the color scheme to all white so we should be able to have it be less obvious.
